# Jupyter notebook only works in base environment

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebook stopped working as usual suddenly today.

If I launch Jupyter like this then everything works fine in base environment.

```
activate base
jupyter notebook
```

But launching it in any other environment or simply without declaring environment

```
activate XXX
jupyter notebook
```

results as a `localhost:8889/tree` blank page in browser.

Also there are no errors in Jupyter console.

I have reinstalled Anaconda and Jupyter, restarted PC and used ip 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, but nothing helps.

What should I do? I really need to get environments back up fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you activate your conda environment, try to install Jupyter for that environment:

`conda activate XXX
 conda install -c anaconda jupyter`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I see that it is necessary after reinstalling Anaconda, but what I don't get is why it stopped working after just closing and reopening Jupyter today. It worked fine for almost a year now. Anyway, it worked and thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A better way is to have one Jupyter with multiple kernels depending on your environment:

So all you need is:

```
conda activate my_env
(my_env) conda install ipykernel -y
(my_env) python -m ipykernel install --user --name my_env --display-name "My Env"
(my_env) conda deactivate
```

Now you can open Jupyter and you will see “My Env” as a possible kernel. ;)

See: [Anaconda Documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html)