# Jupyter Notebook only opens on base environment (Python 3.7, Windows 10)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm not sure what changed but similarly to this post:

[Jupyter notebook only works in base environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244348/jupyter-notebook-only-works-in-base-environment)

Jupyter notebook only opens when I activate my base environment, ie:

```
C:\Users\user\activate base
(base) C:\Users\user\jupyter notebook
```

This happens on powershell, cmd, and cmder. In the default, unspecified environment, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\user>jupyter notebook

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
  from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 62, in <module>
  from tornado import httpserver
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 29, in <module>
  import ssl
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
  import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

In the default environment, I can call `pip` commands but I get this error. It seems to be related to my first issue above.

```
C:\Users\user>pip install

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem 
confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by 
SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not 
available.")) - skipping
```